# How to check null value of object in decision statement for Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, try-catch, null

I am getting a object value from server as null value when `NSlog` this object.I want to identify it in `if-else` decision statement. How can I check it because nil have reference to a unknown object which not means `NULL`.and i can't compare it with zero too.

How can i identify that this value is `NULL`, i have a crash on this point.I have tried `@try - @catch` block too but all gone in vain.

Any suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Try : if([yourObject isEqual:[NSNull null]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there are many kinds of "null" under Cocoa/Objective C.
But one further thing to note is that `[object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]` is pointlessly complex since `[NSNull null]` is documented to be a singleton so you can just check for pointer equality. See [Topics for Cocoa: Using Null](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html)

So use this :-

```
  if (title == (id)[NSNull null] || title.length == 0 ) title = @"Something";
```

Note how you can use the fact that even if title is nil, title.length will return 0/nil/false, ie 0 in this case, so you do not have to special case it. This is something that people who are new to Objective C have trouble getting used to, especially coming form other languages where messages/method calls to nil crash.

If you want in detail what is the difference between nil, Nil and null, you can check this article [What is the difference between nil, Nil and null.](http://www.makebetterthings.com/objective-c/what-is-the-difference-among-nil-null-nil-in-objective-c/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code to check for NULL values from server:

```
if (nil == str || NSNull.null == (id)str) {

       //Object has Null value

  }
 else{
           // Object has some value
}
```

**str** is string value which contain server value.
This may helps you.

Comment: This is correct because `NSNull` defines a singleton object. (But using the dot-syntax for non-properties is something that many people frown upon :-)

Answer (score 2):

**The Best Approach is :**

```
if([yourObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]]) 
{
    // yourObject is null.
}
else 
{
    // yourObject is not null.
}
```

Comment: Note that `NSNull` defines a *singleton* object, therefore you can actually compare with `==` or `isEqual`, so the other answers are also correct.